# Herdar comentários de um objeto virtual

Tags: c#, documentação

Como posso herdar os comentários dentro da *tag* `<summary>` de um objeto?

Tenho a seguinte classe:

```
class BASE
{
    /// <summary>
    /// String de Conexão a base de dados.
    /// </summary>
    public virtual string CONN { get; set; }

    /// <summary>
    /// Carregar DataTable do Modelo.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="Select">Select do Modelo.</param>
    /// <returns></returns>
    public virtual DataTable LOAD(string Select) => new DataTable();
}
```

Quando crio novas classes a partir dela, as mesmas não herdam os comentários através do `override`
Ex:

```
class SQL : BASE
{
    public override string CONN { get => base.CONN; set => base.CONN = value; }

    public override DataTable LOAD(string Select)
    {
        return base.LOAD(Select);           
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Com o ReSharper (e possível outras ferramentas), você consegue replicar o comentário com Alt+Enter na definição, vai ter uma opção copiar a documentação do base.

Mesmo com essa possibilidade, esteja ciente que quando você esta sobrescrevendo um método ele já não faz o que o sumário dizia, mesmo que chame depois seu base. O correto é fazer um novo sumário falando o que seu método faz.

Comment: E se mesmo assim ainda quiser colocar alguma anotação dá para usar a tag `<see>` apontando a referência. https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/xmldoc/see

Comment: Muito bom, não sabia dessa tag. +1

Answer (score 2):

Tem também a possibilidade de herdar a documentacao, tal como deseja.
Para fazer isso use o [`<inheritdoc cref=""/>`](http://tunnelvisionlabs.github.io/SHFB/docs-master/SandcastleBuilder/html/79897974-ffc9-4b84-91a5-e50c66a0221d.htm)

Exemplo:

```
/// <inheritdoc cref="object.ToString"/>
```